# Regex for detecting a word enclosed but in order

Tags: php, regex, nginx

I have a regex that needs to match up a specific url and load some configuration based on that.
Basically What I am have is `/*[^(search)].php/` This regex needs to match every url that has .php in the end but parameters may be present `(something.pgp?t=19)` except for the urls that have `search.php`

For example

```
1. http://www.example.com/discuss/viewtopic.php?t=19
2. http://www.example.com/discuss/viewforum.php?f=8
3. http://www.example.com/discuss/search.php?f=8
```

Among the above three urls the regular expression needs to be able to match 1 & 2 but not 3.
Any help is much appreciated thanks.

**EDITED**
However it should not be matching any other urls that does not include .php in it.
`www.example.com/something` should not be matched.

Comment: `[^..]` is still a character class, not an enclusion.

Comment: Do you really need one regexp, or you need nginx to process these urls differently?

Comment: I need to serve all the .php files with fpm but except for search.php which should be left to phusion-passenger actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [this](http://regex101.com/r/pE2iH9/1):

```
/.+?(?<!search)\.php(?<params>.*)/
```

the key is the non-greedy 'anything' `.+?` : it crawls up the string one by one, always checking for "look behind you and don't see 'search', followed by .php: `(?<!search)\.php`, followed by the named group which are the optional query string params.

Note that this simple regex is pretty permissive, and assumes that .php *alone* signifies a "php URL" - you could get crazy complicated validating URL's.

Comment: This solved the problem and is found to be a complete solution thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem in `/*[^(search)].php/`**

- `[^ ]` negates of character class

  so `[^(search)]` here would match anything other than `(` or `s` or `e` or `a` etc

**Solution**

You can use a look behind assertion as

```
^.*(?<!search\.php)\?([^=]=)+\d+$
```

will match 1 and 2

Example : http://regex101.com/r/bJ3vG1/4

**What it doess?**

- `(?<!search\.php)` negative lookbehind. asserts that the regex is presceded not by `search.php`
- `\?[^=]=\d+` matches parameters

**Edit**

If the parameter part is optional, a lengthier regex would do the purpose

```
.*(?<!search\.php)\?([^=]=)+\d+$|^[^?]*(?<!search\.php)$
```

Example : http://regex101.com/r/bJ3vG1/3

Comment: OP wrote: **This regex needs to match every url that has .php in the end**

Comment: @anubhava my regex wont work in that case. But i safely assumed so because op wrote like *.php in the end but parameters may be present* . Will think of something better :)

Comment: @anubhava I have edited the answer. could you take a look at it and suggest edits if any

Comment: While this answer is accurate on regexp, it's wrong as long as nginx is concerned.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the statement "parameters may be present" doesn't mean the regex should be statically coded around a param named f and t. these are just examples.

Comment: @sweaver2112 I have edited the answer. Hope its fine now

Answer (score 1):

Just use two different location (make sure `search.php` is before general `*.php`)

```
location ~ /search\.php$ {
    # config for phusion-passenger
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    # config for php-fpm
}
```

Nginx strip off request parameters while searching for match, so you don't have to care about them.

Comment: Wouldn't it also load the configuration for .php while serving search.php pages ?

Comment: No. Nginx uses first matched regexp location. That's why it's important to put locations in right order.

Comment: And, unlike apache or lighttpd nginx don't combine locations

Comment: hmm so the search.php location should not have done anything and only the .php should have been served by php-fpm . However I still find the search.php is being served to php-fpm.

Comment: Well, then post full nginx config

Comment: Answer from @sweaver2112 has worked for now but if you would like to seek what i did wrong here is full server config [link](https://gist.github.com/xecutioner/92cc25032dc3fd34878e)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65572/discussion-between-xecutioner-and-alexey-ten).